# cannot import python package from dist-packages

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, distutils, python-3.11

On Ubuntu, with multiple python installation and python 3.11 not the default one.
When I try to install keyring on python3.11

```
/usr/bin/python3.11 -m pip install keyring
```

I get

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: keyring in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (10.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: secretstorage in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from keyring) (2.3.1)
```

but if I create a python file (p01_keyring.py) with just

```
import keyring
```

in it and run it with

```
/usr/bin/python3.11 /home/PythonProjects/venv_airflowI/p01_keyring.py
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/adm_difolco_e/airflow/dags/p01_keyring.py", line 1, in <module>
    import keyring
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keyring/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .core import (set_keyring, get_keyring, set_password, get_password,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keyring/core.py", line 13, in <module>
    from . import backend
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keyring/backend.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .util import properties
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/keyring/util/properties.py", line 1, in <module>
    from collections import Callable
ImportError: cannot import name 'Callable' from 'collections' (/usr/lib/python3.11/collections/__init__.py)
```

how can I import keyring from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages